How to filter() from a user input?
I want to obtain an array from a user input using a prompt and then use that array to filter() and get a specific array.
I have used the following:
var number = prompt("write your number","");

var matrix = number.split("");

and I get the desired array but when I applied the filter() method to the matrix array it does not seem to work. I would like to get an array with just the numbers 3s.
The code that I present here works because I have defined the array in the code itself. But I want to use a user input instead.
<script>
        
var matrix = [3,2,2,3,2,3];
        
function find_3(value) {
            
  return (value === 3);

}
        
var result = matrix.filter(find_3);
        
document.write(result);
        
</script>


Did you try parsing the input? '3' !== 3.

number.split("").map(Number), or Array.from(number, Number).

Unless you're positive the characters in number are all ASCII, using split("") will not work. See How can I get a character array from a string?

Thanks, using:   number.split("").map(Number); solved the issue.

After getting the input (as a string) and splitting it into a string[], you will need to map the values to a Number[] by calling parseInt.


const
  number = prompt("Enter a sequence digits", ""), // 322323
  vector = number.split("").map(n => parseInt(n, 10)), // [3,2,2,3,2,3]
  result = vector.filter(find_3); // [3, 3, 3]

document.write(result); // 3,3,3

function find_3(value) {  
  return value === 3;
}




Remember that the values obtained from a prompt is a string, so, basically, you are not getting
[1,2,3,4]

But getting:
['1','2','3','4']

To fix this, you can transform those strings into numbers:
const matrix = number.split("").map(Number);


Maybe in your case could be sufficient to use simple equality ==:


var number = prompt("write your number","");
var matrix = number.split("");
        
function find_3(value) {            
  return (value == 3); // '==' instead of '==='
}
        
var result = matrix.filter(find_3);
document.write(result);



Reason: prompt() returns a string instead of a number.
Otherwise you would need to parse user input, somewhere:


var number = prompt("write your number","");
var matrix = number.split("");
        
function find_3(value) {            
  return (Number.parseInt(value) === 3); // Parse a string to a number.
}
        
var result = matrix.filter(find_3);
document.write(result);






const X = 3;
const result = []
const totalElements = prompt("Enter total no of elements: ");


for (let counter = 1; counter <= totalElements; counter++) {
  const n = Number(prompt(`Enter element no ${counter} :`))
  if (n === X) {
    result.push(n);
  }
}

console.log('Result : ', result);




You should explain your snippet in addition to providing code.

The above code snippet is just 3 simple steps get total number of element, then take all the inputs from user and then simply save elements only in array if it satisfies our usecase otherwise there is no sense of first take all the elements in the array and then filter out it (you may think of it like an optimization we can do here), its i guess very much intutive
